# Possible EOL issue during unrar?

Tags: linux, rar, unrar

I have large CSV file that I have compressed with WINRAR in windows 8.

After uploading the file to Centos 7 x64 on my VPS, I used unrar. The file is exactly the same size as it should be after being uncompressed but when I run my import script exactly half the number of rows are imported.

The same script works file locally so my hunch is that rar/unrar might be doing something to EOL?

Just wondered if anyone has experienced anything like this before?

Comment: Please show your script.

Comment: I'm uploading a zip file to test. Will post script in the morning if result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rar was not the issue at all. It was a column I was using in the CSV to index the data that was not always present.